# How do I configure Postfix to not accept messages for invalid recipients?

Tags: postfix

As with all mail servers, mine frequently receives spam for invalid recipient addresses.

What configuration values will force Postfix to immediately reject these messages? Furthermore, if Postfix is rejecting them and tries to bounce them back to the origin, how do I force Postfix not to bother deferring the bounce message if it isn’t immediately accepted by the origin?

Comment: is postfix the primary MX for this domain? or is it relaying them to another server?

Comment: @stew Primary. [padding for SF comment character limit]

Answer (score 1):

Set the following options in the /etc/postfix/main.cf

```
bounce_queue_lifetime = 0
local_recipient_maps = unix:passwd.byname $alias_maps
```

If you are using virtual domain/users you should use [virtual_mailbox_maps](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#virtual_mailbox_maps) instead